# How gwt receives the request and loads the ui while in development mode?

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and understood the motive behind creating such good framework. However I could not understand how GWT builds the UI and shows while in development mode.

It is said that while bootstrapping .nocache.js file is loaded in the browser, then this file created a hidden iframe. Then depending on browser and language settings a .cache.html file is loaded in the iframe where all application logic resides.

What I could not understand is how gwt does this in development mode/ hosted mode. Because .cache.html files are not available in development mode. I assume that the sdk receives a request from .nocache.js file regarding the browser details and then generates a .cache.html file for that particular browser and that is loaded in the iframe. My question is how .nocache.js file sends a request to sdk to dynamically generate a .cache.html file? Or does it have something to do with hosted.html and the browser plugin? How the UI and RPC code is loaded while in development mode. For nocache.js file to send a request there must be a server program (Servlet) listening to the request and allowing GWt to start looking for entrypoint class and start generating the UI content.

I could not understand how gwt will come to know about the browser settings and generate the UI? Does hosted.html and browser plugin has something to do with the content generation?

I searched using google, but all my trials went useless. Or may be I searched using wrong search keys. Could anyone please tell me or point me to a link where it is clearly explained?

Comment: It is purely gwt-dev.jar , hosted.html and browser plugin magic. The plugin and hosted mode talk to each other and instead of js the behaviour is driven by java code interpreted by GWT hosted jetty server with gwt-dev jar. The servlet stuff is mapped via RPC interface and web.xml. Your question is too broad scoped for stack overflow type of answer.

Comment: Thank you SSR. I could understand a bit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application is running in development mode, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is actually executing the application code as compiled Java bytecode, using GWT plumbing to connect to a browser window.
[image]

As of GWT 2.0, development mode uses a regular browser instead of an embedded browser. You can use any supported browser.
Out of process hosted mode (OOPHM) is an upcoming replacement for GWT hosted mode debugger. OOPHM allows one to use a standard browser (IE, Safari (32bit) and Firefox) for debugging GWT-client-side code.

With OOPHM you can:

- do modifications to your widgets with no time consuming Java-to-JavaScript recompilation
  set breakpoints to widget code.
- use any advanced browser features and extensions not available in conventional hosted mode (Firebug for example).

Useful links:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DesignOOPHM

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UsingOOPHM

http://www.slideshare.net/allahbaksh/gwt-generators-and-oophm

Have a nice time.

Comment: Thank you Saeed. What I can understand is GWT uses some mechanism called plumbing and serves the UI code and other relevant code. I read the following links and could understand very little. Still I am confused. The articles does not discuss about how bootstrapping process is done in development mode. Can you please explain? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bootstrapping in development mode is done bye deferred binding concept and Generators.

Comment: But deferred binding is done while compiling the project right? Or is it done in development mode also?

Comment: No, it is used for polymorphism and reflection in development mode and used as code generator and dynamic binding in compile time.

Comment: Thank you Saeed. I understood and am putting all the pieces together to understand it as a whole.

Comment: Your welcome, if this answer was useful for you please accept it.

Comment: Hi @Saeed,I would like to brief my understanding about GWT flow in development mode.Browser requests the home page, the script which points to nocache.js in the home page creates a hidden iframe & tries to load cache.html file.It detects the browser & other necessary details & sends it to the server to get the appropriate cache.html page.May be the server intercepts the url and understands that there is a request for cache.html page.Using deferred binding it generates code for the browser & using plumbing mechanism the server communicates with the plugin in browser and page is displayed.

Comment: This link talks about dynamic binding a bit ... (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames)